# How can I set roboto medium in native base project. Currently not able to change the font weight

Tags: react-native, native-base

In react native project, I am using native base but not able to change  the font weight of roboto medium, Font weight 500 is not working

Comment: What does it mean "is not working"?

Comment: yes it was but now working